# Php mysql fetch array repetitive index problem

Tags: php, mysql

I want to remove the number indexes in the following output

> Array ( [0] => 7593 [id] => 7593 [1] => Atakan [ad] => Atakan [2]

intended

> Array ([id] => 7593 [ad] => Atakan [2]

my code

```
     global $durum;
 $array = Array();
 $sql="select * from bird_table_uye order by id desc";
 $query=phpmkr_query($sql,$durum);
 $i=0;


 while ($row=phpmkr_fetch_array($query)) {
  $array[$i]=$row;

   $i++;
 }
 print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
mysqli_fetch_array()
```

rather using

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc()
```

Comment: Your welcome it would be very nice of you if you accept the answer also :)

Comment: Yes of course there are number of libraries to make this job easier one of them is PHPExcel